# Word-Puzzle (ArrayList problems)

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have been creating a Word-Puzzle which I recently got stuck on a index out of bounds problem. This has been resolved however the program is not doing what I would like it to do. The Idea i that the test class will print 3 words in an array e.g. [FEN, GNU, NOB] (and yes they are apparently real english words). Then check to see if the first letter of each word combined is a word and so forth e.g. FGN if so add it to the next ArrayList else start again. Ideal output would be [FEN, GNU, NOB] [FGN, ENO, NUB] for example. However the current output is [FEN, GNU, NOB] [SOY, SOY, SOY] or [FEN, GNU, NOB] [].

The Test Class

```html
public class Test_WordPuzzleGenerator {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  
  System.out.println("Test 1: size 3");
  int size = 3;
  Puzzle.WordPuzzleGenerator.generatePuzzle(size);

 }

}
```

WordGenerator:

```html
public class WordPuzzleGenerator {
static ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
public static void generatePuzzle(int size) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<String> puzzleListY = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> puzzleListX = new ArrayList<String>();
    String randomXWord;
    String letterSize = "" + size;
    makeLetterWordList(letterSize);
    boolean finished = false;
    while ( !finished ) {
        finished = true;
        puzzleListX.clear();
        puzzleListY.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int randomYWord = randomInteger(wordList.size());
            String item = wordList.get(randomYWord);
            puzzleListY.add(item);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < puzzleListY.size(); i++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < puzzleListY.size(); j++) {
                sb.append(puzzleListY.get(j).charAt(i));
            }
            randomXWord = sb.toString();
            if (!wordList.contains(randomXWord)) {
                break;
            }
            puzzleListX.add(randomXWord);
            if (puzzleListX.size() == size){
                finished = false;
            }


        }

    }
    System.out.print(puzzleListY);
    System.out.print(puzzleListX);
}

public static int randomInteger(int size) {
 Random rand = new Random();
 int randomNum = rand.nextInt(size);
 return randomNum;
}



public static void makeLetterWordList(String letterSize) throws FileNotFoundException {

 Scanner letterScanner = new Scanner( new File (letterSize + "LetterWords.txt"));
 wordList.clear();
    while (letterScanner.hasNext()){
  wordList.add(letterScanner.next());
 }
 letterScanner.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you use `i` in the second loop?

Comment: @ajb I dont use I in the nested for loop, also if i do change .charAt(j) to (i) it will only sometimes print 1 word which is correct the remaining times it shows a empty ArrayList. For example 
Test 1: size 3
[ACE, BAD, SKY][ABS]

Comment: i dont understand your _while(!finished)_ loop. it will only run once, since you will never set finished to false again in your loop.

Comment: @B.Kemmer for reference where should I set finish to false in my loop?

Comment: the initial question was why would you even loop at this position if it only run once?

Comment: @B.Kemmer It is for the error checking while the ArrayList is not correct repeat. I have updated the code which may make it a bit clearer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing yourself with that `finished` variable.  Replace the `while` condition with `puzzleListX.size() != size` and your code should work.